# o.s.boot.SpringApplication : Application run failed with CommandLineRunner exception

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I am building some Spring boot application and with the main class I am implementing CommandLineRunner and so the code I want to get executed is present in the overrided run() method. I know similar question is present on stackoverflow but the solution's mentioned over there are not solving my issue's. 
This is application file
``

```
package com.First_Spring.Database_My_Spring;
import com.First_Spring.Database_My_Spring.Entities.Person;
import com.First_Spring.Database_My_Spring.JDBC.Person_JDBC_DAO;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class DatabaseMySpringApplication implements CommandLineRunner{

    @Autowired
    Person_JDBC_DAO person_jdbc_dao;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SpringApplication.run(DatabaseMySpringApplication.class, args);
    }


    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {

        System.out.println( person_jdbc_dao.find_All() );
    }
}
```

``
Below is the application properties file
`

```
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
```

`

Below is the pom.xml file
`

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.First_Spring</groupId>
    <artifactId>Database_My_Spring</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Database_My_Spring</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

`Below is the error I am getting`

```
2020-06-19 19:54:40.072  INFO 22134 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2020-06-19 19:54:40.081 ERROR 22134 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to execute CommandLineRunner
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:798) ~[spring-boot-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:779) ~[spring-boot-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:322) ~[spring-boot-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1237) ~[spring-boot-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) ~[spring-boot-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
    at com.First_Spring.Database_My_Spring.DatabaseMySpringApplication.main(DatabaseMySpringApplication.java:18) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at com.First_Spring.Database_My_Spring.JDBC.Person_JDBC_DAO.find_All(Person_JDBC_DAO.java:18) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.First_Spring.Database_My_Spring.JDBC.Person_JDBC_DAO$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$f0cd1232.invoke(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218) ~[spring-core-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:771) ~[spring-aop-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:749) ~[spring-aop-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139) ~[spring-tx-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:749) ~[spring-aop-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:691) ~[spring-aop-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at com.First_Spring.Database_My_Spring.JDBC.Person_JDBC_DAO$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$e3e35047.find_All(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.First_Spring.Database_My_Spring.DatabaseMySpringApplication.run(DatabaseMySpringApplication.java:25) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:795) ~[spring-boot-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
    ... 5 common frames omitted
```

`

Comment: You have a NullPointerException on line 18 in Person_JDBC_DAO. What's on this line?

Comment: @Simon Martinelli Person_JDBC_DAO is the class present in the data layer which is concerned with the data access operations. I didn't mention that in my code section since I thought error is not something related to that. Do you want me to add that ?

Comment: Yes as I said it's on line 18 in this class